# AWS X-RAY showing weird error while fetching trace summaries for same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I have a lambda who fetch trace summaries from X-RAY for the given time duration on basis of the user. When I enter startTime `17:10:03.021Z` & endTime `17:52:03.097Z` X-RAY is giving me traces present but when I changes time startTime `17:10:03.021Z` & endTime `18:00:03.097Z` it shows no traces present.

```
    var params = {
        EndTime: '2018-11-18T17:52:03.097Z',
        StartTime: '2018-11-18T17:10:03.021Z' ,
        FilterExpression: 'Annotation.User ="username"'
      };
xray.getTraceSummaries(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
      console.log('data.TraceSummaries.length ',data.TraceSummaries.length);
      var numberOfTraceIds = data.TraceSummaries.length;
      if (numberOfTraceIds === 0) {
        console.log('Data empty ',JSON.stringify(data))
        return callback(null, 'no data');
      }
```

This is the piece of code I have written.
Output when the time is changed

```
{ "TraceSummaries": [], "ApproximateTime": "2018-11-18T18:00:00.000Z", 
 "TracesProcessedCount": 0, "NextToken": "****" }
```

In both time cases, traces is available on X-RAY console. How could I resolve this?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X-Ray console calls `GetTraceSummaries` on your behalf and it use the `NextToken` returned from the response to keep calling until it finds something. For directly calling using js SDK you will also need to use the `NextToken` so it has similar behavior with X-Ray console.

Comment: Yes, got my data from NextToken. It use concept similar to pagination.